OpenTelemetry exporter for ActiveMQ Artemis - trying Prometheus as interim step
Any guidelines for getting OpenTelemetry from Artemis apache/activemq-artemis:2.33.0? I'm using OpenTelemetry for the other components and was somewhat blinded by the "built-in" JMX on port 1099, which doesn't seem to work for me. I now have Jolokia JMX bridge on
  - job_name: 'activemq'
static_configs:
  - targets: ['activemq-service:8161']
metrics_path: '/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=%220.0.0.0%22/TotalMessageCount,Active'
basic_auth:
  username: 'admin'
  password: 'admin'

Specifically for Prometheus, but of course that returns a json blob while Prometheus wants a key=value as far as I can tell.
Could someone point me in the right direction please?
For Prometheus:
In broker.xml again for Prometheus:
<metrics>
    <jvm-memory>true</jvm-memory>
    <jvm-gc>true</jvm-gc>
    <jvm-threads>true</jvm-threads>
    <netty-pool>true</netty-pool>
    <file-descriptors>true</file-descriptors>
    <processor>true</processor>
    <uptime>true</uptime>
    <logging>true</logging>
    <security-caches>true</security-caches>
    <plugin class-name="com.redhat.amq.broker.core.server.metrics.plugins.ArtemisPrometheusMetricsPlugin"/>
</metrics>

I'm missing something in the Prometheus endpoint, as it is returning json (error message is expected equal, got ":" ("INVALID") while parsing: "{\"request\":").
End goal is to have OpenTelemetry exported, not Prometheus, which was just a step to understand what I'm getting.

Did my answer address your question? If so, please accept it to help other users who have this same question in the future. Thanks!

As noted in the OpenTelemetry Collector documentation, it can handle Prometheus metrics so using the Prometheus plugin in Artemis should work (assuming you installed it correctly).
If you want to actually push data from ActiveMQ Artemis to OpenTelemetry then you'll need to implement your own plugin which uses the OtlpMeterRegistry from Micrometer.
